# Best way to create placeholder labels?

Tags: floats, labels

I'm trying to reference a number of supplementary material (i.e. videos) which cannot be included directly in the LaTeX document for practical reasons. However, I still would like them to have an "order" for referencing (e.g. Video 1, Video 2, etc...) that I could swap around as needed.

Right now the best I could do is to define a new float style and create empty floats with labels, like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{video}{tbhp}{lst}%[section]
\floatname{video}{Video}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum (Video \ref{vid:example}).

\begin{video}
\label{vid:example}
\end{video}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that this only seems to work if I add a caption or some visual element to the float, but I was trying to avoid this and have it be used only for numbering purposes.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: If I understand this: You are using fake labels, no captions, it's not even necessary to have floats then?

Comment: Yeah, no floats are necessary, but is there another way to just have fake labels in the middle of the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working `\label` needs a `\refstepcounter{}` to be used before, with the relevant counter, say `video`.

To get this more convenient, use a wrapper, say `\genvidlabel` with some argument that has the actual label suffix, say `example` etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcounter{video}
\newcommand{\genvidlabel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{video}\label{vid:#1}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{video}{video}{videos}
\Crefname{video}{Video}{Videos}


\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum (\Cref{vid:example}, whereas in \Cref{vid:otherexample} it's shown where the missing ballots of Florida of the 2000 US elections can be found (;-))


\genvidlabel{example}

\blindtext

\genvidlabel{otherexample}



\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works and this looks like a great solution, but in my actual document I get "??" in my references. Do you know of any packages which might interfere with this solution?

Comment: @glopes: I am working on an improvement already

Comment: @glopes you did compile at least twice?

Comment: I compiled it twice. It looks like with the current solution I need to declare the labels before they are used. It's workable, but would there be a way to allow for arbitrary order?

Comment: @glopes: Try the new version, but if you have a different setup, how should I know of this?

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant as they are mostly unrelated graphics packages, but I guess I should know better that in LaTeX nothing is ever really unrelated. Anyway, thanks, I got it working now.

Comment: @glopes: The reason, why the second label produced `??`  was that it appeared on an 'empty' page. This will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{video}{tbhp}{lst}%[section]
\floatname{video}{Video}
\def\Label{\refstepcounter{video}\label}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum (Video \ref{vid:example}).

\begin{video}
\Label{vid:example}
\end{video}


\end{document}
```